# MVC Authentication flow query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, application-design

I am writing a small app to allow users to update their personal information online.

I get them to Authenticate at the start of the process, but would like also to ask them again for their password just before I submit any changes back to the database.

This is the way Amazon works before allowing you to see your basket and checkout.

Is there a sensible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends what your using as a membership provider...

Lets assume you are using System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider then you need to use the 
ValidateUser method....

```
MembershipProvider _provider =  Membership.Provider;

if (_provider.ValidateUser(username,password)){


...the test has passed
}
```

I'm also assuming SSL is in place....which would be good practise.